# Rails3 ERB syntax requires a commented-out ERB block

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error, erb

Going from Rails 2.3.x to Rails 3.0.7 requires a change in ERB syntax that I just don't get.

I am getting a SyntaxError ( unexpected kEND ) and I can make the error go away if I add the following commented-out line before the 'unexpected' kEND:

```
# %><%
```

This doesn't make sense to me and the fix is ugly.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the complete partial template code, and the error can be toggled by removing line # 19:  http://pastie.org/1881607

---

UPDATE:  I changed from ERB to HAML syntax to avoid this completely and have more readable code.

However, I believe the cause was ERB deprecation warnings in other template files included in application layout.  Fixing the ERB deprecation warnings, I believe, would have fixed this problem.

Comment: OMG! Don't use `content_tag` in your ERB files! It is slow and made for helpers. Also I can't read your code. Oh my eyes!

Comment: If you want to pass all your HTML to Ruby - try [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/)!

Comment: @fl00r that ERB syntax style was a lot more readable in Rails 2.x.  Are you saying, for example, I should use div_for instead of content_tag(:div){}?  Or, are you saying I should use neither?

Comment: You should use raw HTML here: `<div><%= some ERB %></div>`. Or use HAML - it is cleaner and you will like it, if you don't like HTML at all

Comment: @fl00r Thanks for the HAML suggestion, I am sure I will hear it a lot next week at RailsConf.

Comment: @fl00r HAML is easy to read... a great advantage.  I don't like writing it yet, but I will stick to it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ a duplicate of my update to the actual question above ]

I believe the cause was ERB deprecation warnings in other template files included in application layout. Fixing the ERB deprecation warnings, I believe, would have fixed this problem.